# Display the bookmark name in the mode line of emacs

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

How can I display the name of a bookmark (from 'bookmark' or 'bookmark+') in the mode line of emacs, instead of the file name?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly strange request, but here you go (works for files and dired buffers):

```
(defun show-bookmarks-mode-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let (bname text)
    (and
     (setq bname (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                     default-directory
                   (buffer-file-name)))
     (setq bname (expand-file-name bname))
     (setq text
           (delq nil
                 (mapcar
                  (lambda (x)
                    (and (equal bname
                                (expand-file-name
                                 (bookmark-get-filename x)))
                         (substring-no-properties (car x))))
                  bookmark-alist)))
     (setq text
           (mapconcat
            #'identity
            text
            ", "))
     (let ((mode-line-buffer-identification
            (propertize text 'face 'mode-line-buffer-id)))
       (force-mode-line-update)
       (sit-for 5))
     (force-mode-line-update))))
```

Could you elaborate on why you need it?